# How to implement a Chained menu in PHP?

Tags: ajax

I want to have a AJAX Function of implementing a chained menu + a result table.

What i need to do:

Firstly, the page populate automatically a vertical menu from MySQL and a result table.

Secondly, when i click an item in the menu, it displays a submenu in a fixed area in the page and a new result table.

Thirdly, when i click an item in the submenu, it displays a sub-submenu in another fixed area in this page and a new result table.

Last, when i click an item in the sub-submenu, it displays a result table.

All the result tables are in the same position. It changes depending on the click in the menus.

I'm lost in how to do that. Do you any ideas about how to implement this? Thanks so much.

**Edit**:

The effect is a little like this: [effect](http://global-download.acer.com/GDHome.aspx?SC=EMEA_18&LC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your First, Second, Third, Last very much looks like [visualjquery.com](http://visualjquery.com/)

I believe it is written in Javascript+jQuery, so you could learn from its source.

Comment: Yes, it's almost what i want. But how to do that?

Comment: I guess, its written in javascript+jQuery, you need to look at viewsource.

Comment: I'm looking at it. But it seems too complex to me.

Comment: You're not going to get a simple answer to a complex question. You need to learn/understand AJAX requests, JSON, the PHP to handle processing and returning requests

Comment: I'm learning AJAX right now, and the request processing and its mechanism is hard for me. I don't expect a simple solution to this question, but i need some direction and explanation.